# UIButton Response to Touch Down Event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to mimic the button behavior of iPhone's Stopwatch app. So I added the following code to Touch Down event of the button.

```
if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Start"])
{
    [sender setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    [sender setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

But the problem is that the text and color don't change as soon as the button is pressed down, which I understand because of what I have as state, forState:UIControlStateNormal. Therefore, in the code above I replaced

```
forState:UIControlStateNormal
```

everywhere with

```
forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateNormal
```

But now the problem is that for as long as button is pressed down, it shows 'Stop' but as soon as I release the button it switches back to 'Start'. I don't understand this behavior. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, I was able to resolve the issue by using a variable isRunning = YES/NO in the if condition as opposed to conditioning on the titleLabel.text. So I do give credit to Signo as he suggested similar approach. But still I would like to understand why the above code behaves as I explained.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the UIControlStateNormal from here:

```
forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateNormal
```

and keep only

```
forState:UIControlStateHighlighted
```

EDIT:

Just another thing you can try is to create an integer_t variable (on your ViewDidLoad and set it to 2) and increase it everytime the button is pressed and check if the number is even or odd.
Code should be something like this:

```
if (intVariable % 2 == 0)
{
    [sender setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateNormal];

}
else
{
    [sender setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateNormal];

}
intVariable++;
```

Comment: I edited my answer, it could sound pretty stupid but I think that the problem is on the If, if you want try the solution i've posted above :)

Comment: Please only answer, if you know the answer.